# Flash CS6 as3: dowload array of images before loading

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, download

I can't figure out how to download all array(~10 pic) of images and then use them on screen. The problem is that in order not to weight the server, the pictures should be **downloaded one time**.

Now I load images like this:
[code specially without the array just for example]

```
    var shirt1 = String("https://static.topsport.lt/sites/all/themes/topsport2/files/images/marskineliai_png/215.png");
    var img1Request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(shirt1);
    var img1Loader:Loader = new Loader();
    img1Loader.load(img1Request);
    myMovieClip.removeChildAt(0);
    myMovieClip.addChild(img1Loader);
```

I'm thinking about somehow in one flash keyframe as3 code load all images, and in second add load images to screen.

p.s. I add and remove array of Child's for the same movieclip symbol.

**[edit]** 
Here's that I try to compile:

**FRAME 1**

```
    function startLoad(e:Event = null):void {

        var marsk1 = String("https://static.topsport.lt/sites/all/themes/topsport2/files/images/marskineliai_png/215.png");
        var img1Request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(marsk1);
        var img1Loader:Loader = new Loader();
        img1Loader.load(img1Request);
        myMovieClip.removeChildAt(0);
        if(_2 != null){

        myMovieClip.smoothing = true;}

        //myMovieClip.addChild(img1Loader).addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, startLoad);

        function achild(){
            myMovieClip.addChild(img1Loader);
        }
    }
```

**FRAME 2**

```
    achild().addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, startLoad);
```

I tried to apply my situation to Andrey Popov suggestion.
Can I import the function from the previous frame? 
Because I'am trying to do it and I get **method not found**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem between frame actionscript connection by taking

```
var img1Loader:Loader = new Loader();
```

and putting it in front of the function. That's how the loader can be accessed on the other frame.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `addEventListener`, and wait until the loading is finished. Then start a new one. Something like this:

```
var currentImage:uint = 0;

function startLoad(e:Event = null):void {
    if (currentImage == 5) {
        // we are all done
        return;
    }

    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    // loader specific stuff..
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, startLoad);
    currentImage++;
}
```

This is a rough pseudo code but the idea is simple - wait for a loader to load, then load new image.

Comment: I've tried to apply your suggestion to my situation, but I think I'm doing something wrong. P.s. For now I didn't use the array, becouse I need simpler exampler to work :)